# How to create faces of cubes missing their top and bottom faces in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm still working on a way to create modular houses with geometry nodes. This is the result I have and the input geometry I use.

[image]

I'm currently getting **stuck at creating floors**. Here is the geometry I manage to isolate (left image), which is the outside visible part of my floor. **I am simply trying to add top and bottom faces to this geometry** (on the right image, done manually as an example). I tried to Z-scale faces to zero and create curves from this to fill curve, but didn't manage to get it working...

[image]

If anyone has an idea that could be explored, I would be greatful !!
Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you create the input geometry?

Comment: Hello again ! You mean the right part of first image? I do it manually : I create the base edges to shape the house I want, and then extrude the height of my first level. Finally, I extrude again the height of my floor, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all looks like a fairly simple task, but it's actually quite tricky.

There are two basic hurdles here:

- The node `Fill Curve` only produces usable results if the individual curves are flat and not overlapping. As soon as they lie on top of each other on different planes, you get unusable meshes.
- The normals of the faces must be correctly aligned, and in this specific situation these cannot be derived by a logical analysis of the indexes.

All in all, you need a lot of nodes to do all this, even if the task is relatively easy to solve:

[image]

So I suggest the following solution:

[image]

1. Separate the parts that are crucial for this project from each other *(You seem to have solved this part of the problem as well)*:

   - Separate the roof and the ground from your mesh.
   - Separate the walls from your floors. I do this here using the edge length *(Adjust this according to your needs)*.
2. Then separate the vertical from the horizontal edges of your floors.
3. To be able to align the orientation of the faces correctly afterwards, I save the position of the lower point of the vertically running edges in each case.
4. Now comes the real part: First I convert the horizontal edges into curves.
5. So that I get closed meshes with the node `Fill Curve` which can be used further, I move these curves first temporarily to far away positions.
6. Then I apply `Fill Curve` and move the points of the meshes back to their intended positions.
7. Now that I have these layers neatly separated at the correct positions, I only need to correct their orientation, and I do that by comparing them with the previously saved position of the lower point of the vertical edges.
8. Finally, the points are just joined into a closed mesh, and your floors are done.

[image]

Comment: Well, I am once again astonished by your answer. Thanks a lot, I was indeed blocked by the fact that "Fill Curve" was giving me only one face whereas I expected multiple for stacked floors. Very smart to offset them temporarly, that's what I missed. Many thanks again !!